# Search and Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, csv, row

I have a table with names, and I want to sort and put all the same names on one row. On which row doesn't matter. I just want to arrange them on one row. The names in one column are not repeated (they're unique), and the names can't be moved from one column to another. The algorithm would search the same name in different columns, and re-arrange them on one row. the names are stored in cvs text file. Once sorted, the sorted array will be saved in a CSV text file. I'm able to print and access the array to perform some basic manipulations, but I'm stuck on way for how to re-arrange the same names on one row. Thank you for your help. Please refer to the image below to see what I mean.

[image]

Before Sorting:

```
Vic John    Jane    Kirk    Amy
Terry   Amy Roger   Ray Tom
Roger   David   Amy Sally   Jane
David   Frank   Gary    Vic Sally
```

After Sorting:

```
Vic John    Jane    Vic Jane
Terry   Amy Amy Ray Amy
Roger   Frank   Roger   Kirk    Tom
David   David   Gary    Sally   Sally
```

Comment: Any specific language to use? And/or preferred temporary data structure?

Comment: good point Jee! it's Java; the sorted output file will be in the csv format (for ease of manipulations later on).